# Unable to install Gapps on Visual Studio Emulator for Android

Tags: android-emulator, visual-studio-emulator

I used to be able to [install Gapps on Visual Studio Emulator for Android](http://codesmells.net/2015/07/27/installing-the-google-play-store-in-the-microsoft-visual-studio-android-emulator/), but not anymore. I am wondering if this has to do with the the update of VSEFA that I installed today. The following error pops up after the Gapps zip file is dropped to an emulator:
[image]

The log has the following:

```
/system/bin/sh: syntax error: '(' unexpected
```

Could anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the space and the (2) in the file name.

Comment: Thank you, John.  It fixes it.